# How was Kepler's field of view chosen?

Tags: kepler

[The Kepler space telescope points to a single place in the sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_space_telescope#Field_of_view), and a quarter of a percent of the sky. How was this field of view chosen? Why did the Kepler team choose to point the telescope there rather than anywhere else?

Comment: fascinating factoid!

Comment: First item up in a google search. https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/189566main_Kepler_Mission.pdf